# Geoserver 2.22.0 installation problem. Images are visibly different

Tags: geoserver, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to install Geoserver on Fedora using Maven
mvn clean install
and got an error. Frankly speaking, I have no ideas, what is the way to solve it. The error is:

```
Test set: org.geoserver.wms.wms_1_1_1.GetMapIntegrationTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 87, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.72 s <<< FAILURE! - in org.geoserver.wms.wms_1_1_1.GetMapIntegrationTest
testNamedPlacesRenderingSelection(org.geoserver.wms.wms_1_1_1.GetMapIntegrationTest)  Time elapsed: 0.102 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError:
Images are visibly different, found 1469 different pixels, against a threshold of 1300
You can add -Dorg.geotools.image.test.interactive=true to show a dialog comparing them (requires GUI support)
        at org.geoserver.wms.wms_1_1_1.GetMapIntegrationTest.testNamedPlacesRenderingSelection(GetMapIntegrationTest.java:2333)




[ERROR] Failures:
[ERROR]   GetMapIntegrationTest.testNamedPlacesRenderingSelection:2333 Images are visibly different, found 1469 different pixels, against a threshold of 1300
You can add -Dorg.geotools.image.test.interactive=true to show a dialog comparing them (requires GUI support)
[INFO]
[ERROR] Tests run: 1392, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 6


[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project gs-wms: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/andlis/geoserver-2.22.0/src/wms/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :gs-wms
```

I would really appreciate any help.

I cannot understand the way of solving the problem...

Answer (score 1):

The test is rendering a map with a legend, and expects the following result:

[image]

The test running on your platform fails to match the expected outcome. The test has 1300 pixels difference threshold to care for differences in font rendering (and some logic to deal with simple antialiasing differences), but on your system, you have 1469 pixels that are different.

May be due to fonts... GeoServer gets built on Linux, Windows and OSX, and on different Linux distributions as well, without triggering that failure, so I'm guessing there is something quite different in that Fedora installation... fonts likely?

If you are building on a system with a graphical UI running, get into the wms module, and run the following:

`mvn test -Dtest=GetMapIntegrationTest#testNamedPlacesRenderingSelection -nsu -Dinteractive.image=true -Djava.awt.headless=false`

You should get a dialog showing a side by side image comparison.

Comment: I got the following:
[ERROR]   GetMapIntegrationTest.testNamedPlacesRenderingSelection:2331->GeoServerSystemTestSupport.getAsImage:1384 expected:<[image/png]> but was:<[application/vnd.ogc.se_xml]>